# Activity rotating itself and back to normal in android 8.1

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation, android-8.1-oreo

My App is running fine for all the android version but I have noticed that in Android 8.1.0 (Oreo) when I go the screen from portrait activity to landscape activity and when I press back button it shows the abnormal behavior.

Screen auto rotate from landscape and returns it to normal.
It looks like Activity is restarting itself.

Below are the activities which is define in the manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Home.TrainingsActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|locale"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

<activity
    android:name=".Home.ProgrammeActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|locale"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We also faced the same issue with Oreo. We actually can't triggered why its happening with the specific OS version. But we do had a solution to cater this problem.
You can add force Orientation to portrait when finishing your landscape activity.
add this this with onBackPressed() methond in ProgrammeActivity.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

this should solve this abnormal behavior :)

Comment: Let me try this solution. Thank you for a quick response :)

Comment: would appreciate it, if this helps you out.

Comment: It works but I have 134 activities in landscape which comes from the portrait mode. I don't think so its a good move to go to each activity and use requestedorientation

Comment: you can handle this with baseActivity, if you have  written 
else write your logic LandScapeBaseActivity, and inherit those activities from that.

Comment: thanks for this solution!!, i've been sitting on this problem for 2 hours.. ><

Comment: excellent, this solves the problem thank you so much for any one is not working please keep  in onDestroy() method.